# How can I read pdf in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, text-extraction

**How can I read pdf in python?**
*I know one way of converting it to text*, but I want to read the content directly from pdf.

Can anyone explain which **module in python is best for pdf extraction**

Answer (score 81):

You can USE PyPDF2 package

```
# install PyPDF2
pip install PyPDF2
```

Once you have it installed:

```
# importing all the required modules
import PyPDF2

# creating a pdf reader object
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader('example.pdf')

# print the number of pages in pdf file
print(len(reader.pages))

# print the text of the first page
print(reader.pages[0].extract_text())
```

Follow [the documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Tried using this package with an order form from Amazon. It found 33 pages but extractText() API was empty for all pages

Comment: @Sanket PyPDF2 was improved a lot in 2022. Give it another shot :-)

Comment: @retsigam PyPDF2 was improved a lot in 2022. Please try it again

Comment: The library went back to its first name `pypdf`

Answer (score 14):

You can use textract module in python

**Textract**

for install

```
pip install textract
```

for read pdf

```
import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/pdf/file', method='pdfminer')
```

For detail **[Textract](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)**

Comment: textract is broken as far as I can tell.

Comment: Textract seems to be dead as well: https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/350

Comment: Update 2023: Still not working to read PDF files.

Comment: Textract has been dead