# How to read pdf file from frontend using Django framework?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am trying to read pdf file content using Django framework. what I have tried till now is

```
def upload(request):
    
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.FILES['document'].name.split('.')[-1] == "pdf":
                input = request.FILES['document'].read().decode()

                print(input)

            
            return HttpResponse('upload Products')

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

`input = request.FILES['document'].read().decode()` 
// This method gives error like 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 72: invalid start byte

`input = request.FILES['document'].read()` I am not able to decode the
**Output**

b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\x9f\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx\x9c\xdd\x1b\xcb\x8e\xe3\xb8\xf1\xde_\xe1\xf3\x02\xee\x88ER\x94\x80\x81\x01\xdbm\x07\xd8\xdbf\x1a\xc8!\xc8\xc9\xc9&Xx\x03d/\xfb\xfb
xa9'Yz\xd8\xed\xe9\xde\x1c\xa6\xd1\x18O\x95$\x92\xf5\xae\x12Y\xea\x9e\xc3\xe6\xf7\xa7\xffn\xbaM\x87P\x1e\xf33l\x86\x14\x9e\x87\xcdo\xff|\xfa\xeb\x0f\x9b\xff<\x85\r\xfd\xfd\xf6\xaf\xa7\x0eo\xc0\xe6\xd7'{\x086W\x1d@C\xaf:\x05\xfd/\xf7
xfe\xfd\xf4\xf3\x0f\x93A\xd1\r\x8a\xf7\x0619\xf8\x87\x8b\x1e^\x9fr\xc6'\x06\xc0\x9f\xd7\x7fl\xfetFj\x86\xcd\xeb\xcf_\xba\xb0{\xfd\xe5\xe9\xf4\xfa\xf4\xd3\xecy\x08\xf0\x9c\xee\x0f\xe8\x9e\xbb\xae\x0c\t\xd7\x8e\xb9\x1fz\xfc?\r\x103M\x00
cA\xe6\x87\xd8\xe3\x1c\xbf>\x11q\x02_\x99P\x12MQ\x16\xd2\x1c\xd3\xe7\xfc\x0c\xd7'\x91\xc2\x8d\xf5\xfe\xf2g\xa2\xfd\xb9\xc4<l~G\x06~DI\xff

Do I have to do anything with content type which is application/pdf

How can we get full path of file in Django ex: C:\Users\Testing\Zee\ZDemo.pdf

Comment: Try `decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Already tried Error [ input = request.FILES['document'].read().decode("utf-8") ] ........'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a different reader.
Save the content that you got uploaded into a folder, and then follow this tutorial:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/

Comment: Is their any way to read the pdf file content without saving the file in the project.

Comment: Seems like you don't need to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795089/how-can-i-read-pdf-in-python

just skip the file.read line, it should work for you straight away

Comment: Is it possible to get full path egs: C:\Users\Testing\Zee\ZDemo.pdf from request.FILES['document']?

Comment: No, unless you have saved it on the server, you cannot get the full path, and when you do save it on the server, you will know where you have saved it :)